# GCC 4.9.1 Unable to find a usable ISL

Tags: gcc, gcc4.9

Trying to configure **/build gcc 4.9.1** from source on **CentOS6.5 (x86_64)**

The **./configure** looks like:

```
mkdir ../gcc-build && cd ../gcc-build && ../gcc-4.9.1/configure 
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib, -L/usr/local/lib/cloog.isl, **-L/opt/x86_64/isl-0.12.2/lib**, 
-L/usr/local/lib/itcl4.0.1, -L/usr/local/lib/libffi-3.0.13, -L/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig, 
-L/usr/local/lib/sqlite3.8.6, -L/usr/local/lib/tcl8.6, -L/usr/local/lib/tdbc1.0.1, 
-L/usr/local/lib/tdbcmysql1.0.1, -L/usr/local/lib/tdbcodbc1.0.1, 
-L/usr/local/lib/tdbcpostgres1.0.1, -L/usr/local/lib/thread2.7.1, -L/usr/local/lib/tk8.6, 
-L/usr/local/lib64, -L/usr/lib64, -L/lib64, -L/usr/lib, -L/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include, 
-I/usr/local/include/atomic_ops, -I/usr/local/include/autoopts, -I/usr/local/include/cloog, 
**-I/opt/x86_64/isl-0.12.2/include**, -I/usr/local/include/freetype2, -I/usr/local/include/gc, 
-I/usr/local/include/libpng16" --prefix=/opt/x86_64/gcc-4.9.1 --disable-multilib 
--disable-libada --with-system-zlib --with-libiconv-prefix=/usr/local/lib 
--with-mpc-include=/usr/local/include --with-mpc-lib=/usr/local/lib 
--with-mpfr-include=/usr/local/include --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/local/lib 
--with-gmp-include=/usr/local/include --with-gmp-lib=/usr/local/lib 
--with-isl=/opt/x86_64/isl-0.12.2 --with-cloog=/opt/x86_64/cloog-0.18.1 --disable-libsanitizer 
--disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-shared 
--enable-threads=posix --enable-libstdcxx --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu 
--enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++
```

But it fails with the following:

- checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries... yes
- checking for version 0.10 of ISL... no
- checking for version 0.11 of ISL... no
- checking for version 0.12 of ISL... no
- configure: error: Unable to find a usable ISL.  See config.log for
  details.

Not sure how else to declare the ISL path, it is also in my **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**.

Comment: Have you, in fact, looked at config.log? It will contain the body of the program that was test-compiled as well as the compiler/linker's complaint about it. The solution will immediately follow.